# ¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar una clase Java creada y compilada desde Netbeans por el cmd?

Tags: java

Este es mi código. ¿Cómo lo ejecuto por cmd ?

```
package promocionesutpl;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class PromocionesUtpl {

    public static double obtenerAleatorios(Double valorMinimo, Double valorMaximo) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return valorMinimo + (valorMaximo - valorMinimo) * rand.nextDouble();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double tabla[] = new double[10];
        String estudiantes[] = {"Andres", "Carlos", "Maria", "Jose", "Camila", "Eduardo", "Estefania", "Jorge", "Paul", "Carolina", "Pedro"};
        double tareas[] = new double[10];
        double examenB1[] = new double[10];
        double examenB2[] = new double[10];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i, x = 0, s = 0, sbj = 0;
        double z = 0, sbz = 0;

        double apro=0;
        double repro=0;

        double numeroPromedio = 4;
        double cuestionario1 = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 2.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double cuestionario2 = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 2.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double cuestionario3 = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 2.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double cuestionario4 = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 2.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;

        double cuestionario1SB = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 2.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double cuestionario2SB = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 2.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double cuestionario3SB = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 2.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double cuestionario4SB = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 2.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;

        double suma = 0;
        double tareaProyecto = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 5.9) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double tareaProyectoSB = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 5.9) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double examen1 = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 10.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        double examen2 = Math.round(obtenerAleatorios(0.0, 10.0) * 100.9) / 100.0;
        String nuevo = "";
        System.out.println("/***********************************Actividades en linea Bimestre 1*******************************/");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Actividades Sincronas 1er Bimestre:");
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            estudiantes[i] = estudiantes[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
            nuevo = estudiantes[i];
            System.out.println("Estudiante:" + " " + nuevo);
            x = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 2);
            tabla[i] = x;
            System.out.println("Chat B1:" + "" + tabla[i]);
            //System.out.println("Videocolaboracion:" + "" + tabla[i]);
            if (tabla[i] == 0) {
                System.out.println("");
                z = tabla[i];
                z = 1.00;
                System.out.println("Actividad suplementaria 1er Bimestre:" + "" + z);
            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Actividades Asincronas 1er Bimestre:");
}
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                j = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 2);
                tabla[j] = j;
                System.out.println("Foro o Wiki B1:" + "" + tabla[j]);
                //System.out.println("Wiki:" + "" + tabla[j]);   
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Cuestionarios Parciales Primer Bimestre");

                /*Cuestionarios Parciales 1*/
                for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
                    tabla[k] = cuestionario1;
                    System.out.println("Cuestionario 1 B1:" + " " + tabla[k]);
                }
                /*Cuestionarios Parciales 2*/
                for (int l = 0; l < 1; l++) {
                    tabla[l] = cuestionario2;
                    System.out.println("Cuestionario 2 B1:" + " " + tabla[l]);
                }
                /*Cuestionarios Parciales 3*/
                for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++) {
                    tabla[m] = cuestionario3;
                    System.out.println("Cuestionario 3 B1:" + " " + tabla[m]);
                }

                /*Cuestionarios Parciales 4*/
                for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
                    tabla[n] = cuestionario4;
                    System.out.println("Cuestionario 4 B1:" + " " + tabla[n]);
                }

                double sumaPromedio = cuestionario1 + cuestionario2 + cuestionario3 + cuestionario4;
                double resultadoCuestionarios = sumaPromedio / numeroPromedio;
                System.out.println("TOTAL EVALUACIONES PARCIALES BIMESTRE I:" + " " + resultadoCuestionarios + " /2 ");

                System.out.println("");
                for (int t = 0; t < 1; t++) {
                    tareas[t] = tareaProyecto;
                    System.out.println("TAREA BIMESTRE I:" + " " + tareas[t] + "/6");
                }

                System.out.println("");
                for (int ex1 = 0; ex1 < 1; ex1++) {
                    examenB1[ex1] = examen1;
                    System.out.println("EXAMEN BIMESTRE I:" + " " + examenB1[ex1] + "/10");
                }

                System.out.println("");

                double totalB1 = resultadoCuestionarios + tareaProyecto + examen1 + x + j + z;
                System.out.println("TOTAL ACTIVIDADES EN LÍNEA BIMESTRE I: " + " " + totalB1 + " " + "/20");

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("/***********************************Actividades en linea Bimestre 2*******************************/");
                System.out.println("");

                for (s = 0; s < 1; s++) {
                    s = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 2);
                    tabla[s] = s;
                    System.out.println("Chat B2:" + "" + tabla[s]);
                    //System.out.println("Videocolaboracion:" + "" + tabla[i]);
                    if (tabla[s] == 0) {
                        System.out.println("");
                        sbz = tabla[s];
                        sbz = 1.00;
                        System.out.println("Actividad suplementaria 2do Bimestre:" + "" + sbz);
                    }

                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Actividades Asincronas 2do Bimestre:");

                    for (sbj = 0; sbj < 1; sbj++) {
                        sbj = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 2);
                        tabla[sbj] = sbj;
                        System.out.println("Foro o Wiki B2:" + "" + tabla[sbj]);
                        //System.out.println("Wiki:" + "" + tabla[j]);   
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("Cuestionarios Parciales Segundo Bimestre");

                        /*Cuestionarios Parciales 1*/
                        for (int sbk = 0; sbk < 1; sbk++) {
                            tabla[sbk] = cuestionario1SB;
                            System.out.println("Cuestionario 1 B2:" + " " + tabla[sbk]);
                        }
                        /*Cuestionarios Parciales 2*/
                        for (int sbl = 0; sbl < 1; sbl++) {
                            tabla[sbl] = cuestionario2SB;
                            System.out.println("Cuestionario 2 B2:" + " " + tabla[sbl]);
                        }
                        /*Cuestionarios Parciales 3*/
                        for (int sbm = 0; sbm < 1; sbm++) {
                            tabla[sbm] = cuestionario3SB;
                            System.out.println("Cuestionario 3 B2:" + " " + tabla[sbm]);
                        }

                        /*Cuestionarios Parciales 4*/
                        for (int sbn = 0; sbn < 1; sbn++) {
                            tabla[sbn] = cuestionario4SB;
                            System.out.println("Cuestionario 4 B2:" + " " + tabla[sbn]);
                        }

                        double sumaPromedioSB = cuestionario1SB + cuestionario2SB + cuestionario3SB + cuestionario4SB;
                        double resultadoCuestionariosSB = sumaPromedioSB / numeroPromedio;
                        System.out.println("TOTAL EVALUACIONES PARCIALES BIMESTRE II:" + " " + resultadoCuestionariosSB + " /2 ");

                        System.out.println("");
                        for (int sbt = 0; sbt < 1; sbt++) {
                            tareas[sbt] = tareaProyectoSB;
                            System.out.println("TAREA BIMESTRE II:" + " " + tareas[sbt] + "/6");
                        }

                        System.out.println("");
                        for (int ex2 = 0; ex2 < 1; ex2++) {
                            examenB2[ex2] = examen2;
                            System.out.println("EXAMEN BIMESTRE II:" + " " + examenB2[ex2] + "/10");
                        }

                        System.out.println("");
                        double totalB2 = resultadoCuestionariosSB + tareaProyectoSB + examen2 + s + sbj + sbz;
                        System.out.println("TOTAL ACTIVIDADES EN LÍNEA BIMESTRE II: " + " " + totalB2 + " " + "/20");

                        double valorFinal = totalB1 + totalB2;
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("TOTAL DEL CURSO ES : " + " " + valorFinal+"/40");

                        if(valorFinal>=28){
                            System.out.println("APROBADO");
                            apro+=1;
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("DEBE RENDIR EXAMEN FINAL Y/O SUPLETORIO");
                            double acm = valorFinal * 60/100;
                            System.out.println("EL 60% DEL TOTAL OBTENIDO /40 ES: " + " " + acm);
                            double fin = acm + valorFinal;
                            if(fin>=16){
                            System.out.println("APROBADO EN EL EXAMEN FINAL"+ " " + fin);
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("REPROBADO EN EL EXAMEN FINAL CON "+ " " + fin);
                                repro+=1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Con buscar un pelin en google se encuentra `java PromocionesUtpl`

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar debes compilar el código que tienes escrito en tu fichero PromocionesUtpl.java. Como la clase PromocionesUtpl pertenece al paquete promocionesutpl, debes situar el fichero PromocionesUtpl.java en un directorio llamado promocionesutpl. 
Para compilar lanzas el comando:

```
javac promocionesutpl\PromocionesUtpl.java
```

Este comando lo lanzas desde el directorio padre de promocionesutpl.

Esto te genera un fichero binario llamado PromocionesUtpl.class.
Ahora ya puedes ejecutar el fichero binario, con el siguiente comando:

```
java PromocionesUtpl
```